# Is it possible to retrieve the namespace of a raised error?

Tags: error-handling, xquery, basex

When I raise an error from within an XQuery query, for instance with:

```
error( fn:QName( 'http://example.com', 'XMPL0001' ), 'Conflict' )
```

... the following is returned by BaseX (be it when communicating with the server, or from within the GUI)

```
Stopped at ., 1/7:  
[XMPL0001] Conflict
```

Is it somehow possible to retrieve the namespace of the error (in this case `http://example.com`) as well?

I'm using a customized PHP client and I would like to use this information to prevent possible (future) conflicts with my custom error codes and parse the errors to throw either a standard `BaseX\Exception` or a custom `SomeNamespace\Exception`, depending on the namespace of the error.

I could, of course, simply use another error code pattern than the typical `ABCD1234` XQuery pattern, to prevent possible (future) error code conflicts, but the possible use of a namespace appeals to me more, because I can then define an uniform `Exception` interface, such as:

```
interface ExceptionInterface
{
    public function getCategory(); // the 4 alpha character part
    public function getCode();  // the 4 digit part
}
```

---

I'm currently using BaseX 7.7.2, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can retrieve information about the error using [a few variables in the error namespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-try-catch), which are in scope of the try-catch statement, like so:

```
declare namespace err = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors";

try {
    error( fn:QName( 'http://example.com', 'XMPL0001' ), 'Conflict' )
}
catch * {
    namespace-uri-from-QName($err:code)
}
```

This assumes that you are using XQuery 3.0.

Comment: Aha, I see! You've shown me very useful information about error handling, which I was not aware of. However, since this actually `catch`es the error, my PHP client will not be notified of an *actual* error occurring anymore. I could probably signal a caught error, in stead of a regular result, by returning an `<error>` element, for instance (and perhaps that's even a more appropriate strategy than my current). But I was hoping the error mechanism I'm currently relying on would provide a little more detail about the error. You wouldn't happen to know of such a mechanism, would you?

Comment: I'm glad! What PHP sees is BaseX specific though. Maybe you could emulate/rewrite the BaseX behavior in the catch clause, including output and HTTP status code if it communicates over HTTP and if BaseX lets you change this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The trouble is: I wouldn't be able to emulate the low-level bytes that the [server protocol](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Server_Protocol#Command_Protocol) uses to signal an *actual* error. But no worries, you've given me enough input to a) either stick with what I have now (and just ignore the error namespace) or b) go with returning the `<error>` element and use *that* as an error signal. So, thanks again for your valuable information!