# Is it possible to dynamically declare a default namespace from an external variable?

Tags: xquery, xml-namespaces, basex

For all XQuery queries I execute, I define a default element namespace, like so:

```
declare default element namespace 'http://example.com';
(: rest of the query :)
```

But to hardcode this namespace is kind of cumbersome. Can I dynamically define a default namespace, from an external variable?

It tried:

```
declare default element namespace $namespace;
(: error: Expecting quote, found '$'. :)
```

.. and:

```
declare variable $namespace external;
declare default element namespace $namespace;
(: error: Default declarations must be declared first. :)
```

... but they don't work, unfortunately.

---

I'm currently using BaseX 7.7.2, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is only possible to statically declare default namespaces, as the grammar only allows for a URILiteral in this place. The default element namespace is in the static context of the query.

However, you can build QNames out of a variable containing the namespace dynamically (from a variable). You can build new elements with such QNames with computed element constructors. The XPath navigation, however, would be more involved, because you will have to filter namespaces explicitly.

Comment: I've think I'll simply wrap my queries in an a generic query template then, such that I only have to declare the namespace in one place. Also, I think I might use this generic wrapper as a `try .. catch` block as well then (relating to my other question [you answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38124483/165154)), with a generic `<error>` generator in the `catch` block. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It's generally assumed that if you know the local names of the elements in the source document statically, then you will also know their namespaces statically. This assumption is not always correct; you sometimes encounter a family of namespaces (e.g. different versions of a namespace) that use the same local names; but XQuery (and XSLT) aren't well designed to handle this scenario.

So if you know the names of the elements statically, and use path expressions like invoice/customer/address, then the names in this path are simply a shorthand for the full expanded names, and it's assumed that the shorthand can be resolved by the compiler. That's why the namespace declarations are all fixed statically.

If you don't know the names of the elements you are querying statically, then you're probably writing a query that uses wildcards (e.g. child::*) rather than explicit local names like "invoice". In that case the default namespace declaration never comes into play anyway.

So the only situation I can see where you have trouble is the scenario above where multiple namespaces use similar sets of local names. Most people advise against using namespaces that way, for that very reason, but unfortunately not everyone has followed this advice.